# Unable to create session while mocking Appium's behavior using WireMock

Tags: automation, mocking, appium, junit5, wiremock

I am trying to mock Appium’s behavior using WireMock.

Problem I am facing is: my POST stub is able to respond me with the response code I have set (which I have monitored using Wireshark), but it is throwing exceptions related to session creation.

POST stubs I have tried for creating session for reference:

**- Trial 1:**

```
wireMockRule.stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/wd/hub/session”)).

withRequestBody(matching(“JSON representation of set of desired capabilities specific to application"))

.willReturn(aResponse().
withStatus(200).

withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json”).

withBody("{\"sessionId\":\"e523dc70-c068-46e7-b966-8462401119b4\",\"status\":0,\"value\":\"Created Session\"}")));
```

**Outcome**: “It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible” exception.

**Trial 2:** Just removed request body from above stub

```
wireMockRule.stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/wd/hub/session”))

.willReturn(aResponse().

withStatus(200).

withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json”).

withBody("{\"sessionId\":\"e523dc70-c068-46e7-b966-8462401119b4\",\"status\":0,\"value\":\"Created Session\"}")));
```

**Outcome**:

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session” exception.

**Environment reference:**

Java-client of Appium: 6.0.0

Selenium standalone server: 3.12.0

Selenium client of Java: 3.12.0

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This does not really seem to related to WireMock?

Maybe you can switch to the [.NET version from WireMock](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net) to simulate your calls?